# How does Oracle's Bitwise operations work on decimal NUMBERS?

Tags: oracle, t-sql

I am working on porting pl/sql to tsql and i am coming to BITAND operators working on NUMBERS such as 2.70703. How does oracle perform a bitwise operation on a NUMBER 2.70703? Is it converting it to the cloest binary number, rounding, truncating or something else? Tsql only takes integers. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BITAND` truncates operands toward zero and performs bit operation based on 2's complement 128-bit binary representation of integer values.